# How do I correct this error so that the terminal will accept my input?

Tags: ln

```
$ ln -s/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/

ln: illegal option -- /
usage: ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [link_name]
       ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file ... linkname_dir
       link source_file link_name
```

I am currently trying to install the compiler for visual studio code, but
the terminal won't allow me to input without an error. How do I correct this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You miss one space, the command should be like:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```